# Suppress Gradle's JavaExec output

Tags: gradle

I have gradle code below and I don't know how to avoid huge output generated by `JavaExec` task. I haven't found any option of `JavaExec` for it. If anyone knows better way of ignoring it, please share it.

```
def getStubOutput() {
    return new FileOutputStream(new File("${buildDir}/temp"))
}

configure(project(':jradius:dictionary-min')) {
    evaluationDependsOn(':jradius')
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir "${projectDir}/target/dictionary-src"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile project(':jradius:core')
    }
    task genSources(type: JavaExec) {
        main = 'net.jradius.freeradius.RadiusDictionary'
        classpath configurations.all
        args = ["net.jradius.dictionary", "${projectDir}/../freeradius/dict-min", "${projectDir}/target/dictionary-src"]
        maxHeapSize = "800m"
        standardOutput = getStubOutput()
    }
    jar {
        archiveName = "jradius-dictionary-min-1.1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    }
    genSources.dependsOn ':jradius:cloneJradius' 
    compileJava.dependsOn genSources
}
```

Comment: Maybe just assign `null` to `standardOutput`?

Comment: Which is the way of assignment? task genSources(type: JavaExec) { ... standardOutput = null } gives an error
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
> outputStream == null!

Comment: So it obviously doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

I simply use a dummy OutputStream that does nothing in its `write` method:

```
def dummyOutputStream = new OutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) {}
}

exec {
    executable = name
    standardOutput = dummyOutputStream
    errorOutput = dummyOutputStream
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A great solution I came across is to modify the logging level of the task.  If you set it to INFO, then it will squelch all the output of that task, unless gradle is run with --info.

Alternatively, you can set the level to LogLevel.QUIET, which will completely silence it.

```
task chatty(type: Exec) {
    ....
    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.INFO
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, but I have almost forgotten about this script and concerned:)
Anyway, thanks! Does that LogLevel. squelches stdout from this task only? Have no chance to check now, but for the future...

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does for me. The other tasks are unaffected

Comment: This had no effect for me with gradle 3.3

Comment: This works for me (gradle 4.2.1).
You may want to add: `logging.captureStandardError LogLevel.INFO`.
Also, `LogLevel.QUIET` is actually higher than `LogLevel.INFO`.
If you want to silence the task output you should use the lowest level: `LogLevel.DEBUG`. Then you will only see the output if you run gradle with `--debug`.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comment I thought that `standardOutput` can be set to `null` but the following piece of code (taken from: `org.gradle.process.internal.AbstractExecHandleBuilder`) shows that's not possible:

```
public AbstractExecHandleBuilder setStandardOutput(OutputStream outputStream) {
    if (outputStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("outputStream == null!");
    }
    this.standardOutput = outputStream;
    return this;
}
```

What You can do is to redirect the output to temporary file (file will be deleted!) with this oneliner:

```
task genSources(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'net.jradius.freeradius.RadiusDictionary'
    classpath configurations.all
    args = ["net.jradius.dictionary", "${projectDir}/../freeradius/dict-min", "${projectDir}/target/dictionary-src"]
    maxHeapSize = "800m"
    standardOutput = { def f = File.createTempFile('aaa', 'bbb' ); f.deleteOnExit(); f.newOutputStream() }()
}
```

or if You'd like to save this output for further reading:

```
task genSources(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'net.jradius.freeradius.RadiusDictionary'
    classpath configurations.all
    args = ["net.jradius.dictionary", "${projectDir}/../freeradius/dict-min", "${projectDir}/target/dictionary-src"]
    maxHeapSize = "800m"
    standardOutput = new File(project.buildDir, 'radius.log').newOutputStream()
}
```

The last option is to add apache commons-io to script dependencies and set `standardOutput` to `NullOutputStream`. In can be done as follows:

```
import static org.apache.commons.io.output.NullOutputStream.NULL_OUTPUT_STREAM

buildscript {

   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
   }
}

task genSources(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'net.jradius.freeradius.RadiusDictionary'
    classpath configurations.all
    args = ["net.jradius.dictionary", "${projectDir}/../freeradius/dict-min", "${projectDir}/target/dictionary-src"]
    maxHeapSize = "800m"
    standardOutput = NULL_OUTPUT_STREAM
}
```

That's all that comes to my head.

Answer (score 2):

This disables the standard output from a `javaExec` task:

```
task myCustomTask(type: javaExec) {
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    classpath = ...
    main = ...
    args ....
}
```